# Why would this string be returning false in PHP when realpath()'d?

Tags: php, path, directory-structure

Here is my string

```
$newPath = '/~new/assets/js/../packages/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js';
```

Now check this output

```
var_dump($newPath); // string(64) "/~new/assets/js/../packages/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"
var_dump(realpath($newPath)); // bool(false)
```

Does anyone know why this would be returning false on me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, *you* were the guy who provided the [**manual link**](https://www.php.net/realpath) in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338912/is-there-an-inbuilt-way-in-php-to-parse-a-string-like-this-path-to-up-so)! Don't just link it, read it. :)

> realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.

Comment: My eyes seem to read everything except what they should in the PHP docs.

Comment: Happens :) but @Decipher's answer is also worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out by adding

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

After your statement. The possible errors are described in the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

A quick look on the php.net definition of realpath shows this note, which may be pertinent:

> **Note:** The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise **realpath()** will return **FALSE**.